# Inequality using only algebraic ''moves''

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How can I verify the following inequality using only algebraic passages? 
$$
5^\frac{1}{3} + 6^\frac{1}{2} > or < 4 
$$

Comment: "Passages" is an unusual word choice. Are we trying to find whether it is less than $4$ or greater than $4$? Because if that is the case, "verify" is the wrong term.

Comment: Oh sorry mapierce271, as you can see i'm very bad at english...So yes, the sense is that one you indicate

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$\sqrt[6]{25}+\sqrt[6]{216} \ge 2\sqrt[12]{5400} > 2\sqrt[12]{4096}$$

Answer (score 2):

$5>\left(\frac53\right)^3$, so $5^{1/3} >\frac53$.

$6>\left(\frac73\right)^2$, so $6^{1/2} > \frac73$.

Hence $5^{1/3} + 6^{1/2} > 4$.

Comment: Nice approach...+1.